# Use existing serial field with same counter across content types

Tags: 7, entities

how do I use existing Serial field in other content types with same counter db table? 
Have 2 CCKs, cck-A has a serial field (auto increment) (ParticipantNumber), added same ParticipantNumber serial field (add existing field) in cck-B.
But the serial field value for both CCKs have independent auto incremental value.

How do I make the ParticipantNumber values be incremental (and Unique) across cck A and B? (just like node nid)

Comment: Or if it is not possible, how else can I achieve to have same field that is auto incremental across cck A and B?

Comment: They have the same field machine name?

Comment: yes they have, I mean I am using the same field in both the content types. I used "Add existing field" while adding the field in second content type..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Serial type, I added Integer field, and added the same field (add existing field) in other content type as well. And In the **hook_entity_presave**, I query for the MAX(field_value), increment and assign for the current node/entity.